# How to run javascript after jquery and dom has finished loading in c#?

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net, sharepoint-2010

In my asp.net/c# solution, I am loading the jquery library with this

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="jquery_js" name="/_layouts/PDF Library/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" runat="server" OnDemand="False" Localizable="False" />
```

Now, in c# code, how can I insert javascript, that will only run when the jquery library is done loading and the dom is finished loading too.
I can insert javascript like this:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(someControl, typeof(string), "AutoComplete", js_call, true);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Erm, `$(document).ready(handler)`? http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(window).load(function(){
   //this will run after dom is loaded
});
```